# PHP5 object to SOAP server

Tags: php, soap

I've just design a CMS using plenty of classes. My CMS is written in PHP. I wish to add to it an easy SOAP API to it. Every object have getter and setter (`$obj->get_this()` and `$obj->set_this($value)`). Of course, all getter and setter are public method. All other stuff in object are at least protected but mainly private. Every object have a `get_all()` method that set all private object variable into a public object variable (for example: there is a private `$this->pName`, a public `$this->name` and get_all()` function populate all public variable).

The Soap server I dream of would be the least code possible, the most extendable possible, using getter and setter to get/set variable, and I wish not to rewrite wsdl each time I have to add a function / method / variable. 
I had Googled for it and look here for a simple process, but couldn't find code/lib/process that would be simple and extendable. I looked into nusoap, but using a PHP4 compatible lib doesn't seem to be a good solution.
Did I miss something ? Is there some lib / function / method / process I missed?

Comment: SOAP is fairly old hat now - wouldn't REST be simpler?

Comment: This has to be considered too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days thinking :
I found this library: https://github.com/piotrooo/wsdl-creator

It doesn't feet my needs, but somehow ...

I've made a class for everyone of my object, just to filter what I want to be available or not in the API.

To write less, I made 2 bash code to pre-generate all code :
For the getter:

```
for j in $(for i in $(cat myclass.class.php | grep public | egrep 'get_') ; 
do 
    echo $i | grep -v public | grep -v function  
done ) 
do  
    method=$(echo $j | awk -F'(' '{ printf $1'} )
    helper=$(echo $method | sed -e "s/get_//g" | sed -e "s/_/ /")
    param=$(echo $method | sed -e "s/get_//g" )
    echo '/**'; 
    echo '* @desc Get '$helper; 
    echo '* @param int $id';  
    echo '* @return string $'$param; 
    echo '*/' ; 
    echo 'public function '$method'($id)'; 
    echo '{'; 
    echo '    $this->load($id);'; 
    echo '    return $this->obj->'$j';' ;  
    echo '}' ; 
done
```

For the setters:

```
for j in $(for i in $(cat myclass.class.php | grep public | egrep 'set_') ; 
do 
    echo $i | grep -v public | grep -v function 
done ) 
do  
    method=$(echo $j | awk -F'(' '{ printf $1'} )
    helper=$(echo $method | sed -e "s/set_//g" | sed -e "s/_/ /")
    param=$(echo $j | awk -F'(' '{ printf $2'} | sed -e "s/)$//g")
    echo '/**'; 
    echo '* @desc Set '$helper; 
    echo '* @param int $id';  
    echo '* @param string '$param; 
    echo '* @return bool $res'; 
    echo '*/' ; 
    echo 'public function '$method'($id,'$param')'; 
    echo '{'; 
    echo '    $this->load($id);'; 
    echo '    return $this->obj->'$j';' ;  
    echo '}' ; 
done
```

These bash code are **not** for production use, but they can help to write less.

About REST, that is my next mission ...